# github - how to set it up so collaberators get email alerts

Tags: github

I'd like the collaborators on my project to get emails when there is a new issue, comment, or pull request.

How do I set that up?  I couldn't seem to find the answer on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click "Admin" for your repository, and then "Hooks" on the left, you'll be able to select the Email Service Hook for that repository.  (Click "Email".)  That will only let you add one address, but you can make that a mailing list for you and your collaborators.  Alternatively, you could [write your own web-hook](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/).